# How to access data associated with element when using event-delegation

Tags: javascript, performance, dom-events, event-delegation

I am using event-delegation on n-number of rows, my older approach was binding each row with event the code looked something like this:

```
function getDiv (data) {
    var div = $("<div class='theDiv'>");

    div.click(function () {
        console.log(data);
    });

    return div;
}

function getContainer() {
    var i, container;

    container = $("<div class='container'></div>");
    for (i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
        container.append(getDiv(i));
    }
    return container;
}

$("body").append(getContainer());
```

Note: In this approach each row element (`theDiv`) is having access to their data.

Now the question is, I want to bind a single click on `container` and access the data, the event-delegation approach would look like this:

```
function getNewDiv (data) {
    var div = $("<div class='theDiv'>");

    return div;
}

function getNewContainer() {
    var i, container;

    container = $("<div class='container'></div>");
    for (i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
        container.append(getNewDiv(i));
    }

    container.click (function (e) {
        var targetElem = e.target;
        console.dir(e);
        if ($(targetElem).hasClass("theDiv")) {
            console.log("row was clicked");
        }
    })

    return container;
}

$("body").append(getNewContainer());
```

Now, how to access the data associated with each row?

As per my learning:
I can add the data to

- data-*, but this would limit me to simple data type
- $.data associated to element

Is there any other way todo this?

Answer (score 0):

`.on` allows you to do event delegation:

```
container.on('click', '.theDiv', function () {
    //`this` is `.theDiv`.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.data()` inside `getNewDiv()` to store a reference index:

```
function getNewDiv (dataIndex) {
    return $("<div class='theDiv'>").data('idx', dataIndex);
}
```

Then, use each element's data index variable to reference an object in your big array of data:

```
var mydata = [{ ... }, { ... }, { ... }];

container.on('click', '.theDiv', function () {
    var data = mydata[$(this).data('idx')];
    console.log("row was clicked");
});
```

Comment: Any other way? I was thinking of not using the $.data or data-*, well $.data is more elegant but still :)

Comment: @dilliwal the data that you store in each could simply be an index to an array of objects which can be referenced from the single click handler.

Comment: @AbhishekDilliwal I've updated my answer to give an example of how you can keep the data central.

Comment: Thanks Jack, even I thought the same, the only problem with this is, I have to keep track of the dataArray when the dom elements are removed.  keeping this in $.data is better as when we use `remove` of jQuery it removes the data also.

Comment: @AbhishekDilliwal Yeah, I obviously didn't take removing nodes into consideration :)